# jquery adding multiple div containers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, forms

I have a form for posting content onto a wall. We can post pictures on there and text. I have the form content show up in a contenteditable div so the post box displays the image people want to upload and they can type in the div also. I noticed though when people upload an image. It gets prepended like it is supposed to into the div and when they start typing it adds the container for photo around the text also. How can I stop this from happening?

Here is my form code

```
<form id="post-form" action="Scripts/create-post.php" method="post" onsubmit="return setEditable();">
    <input type="hidden" id="posted" name="posted" value=""/>
    <div id="post-message" name="post-message" contentEditable="true"></div>
    <input id="upload-pic" name="upload-pic" type="file"/>
    <button class="post-buttons" onclick="chooseFile(); return false;">Add Photo</button>
    <button class="post-buttons">Add Link</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    <div class="cleared"></div>
</form>
```

Here is the jquery that adds the uploaded photo into the contenteditable div

```
function chooseFile() {
    $("#upload-pic").click();
}

$(document).on('change', "#upload-pic", function(){
    readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input){
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
        $('#post-message').prepend("<div id='post-image-container'><img id='preview'/></div>");
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result); 
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

as you can see when the file is uploaded it triggers a click to add the image into the div and the img is surrounded in a div id post image container. This is what is being added to the text once the img is added to the div.

I know this because of an alert it shows me the value of the div as

```
<div id="post-image-container"><img src='whatever the path is'></div><div id="post-image-container">hello world(if this is what the user typed in)</div>
```

So I managed to find out if the text is in the contenteditable div already or before it, it does not add the extra div tags around the text. It is only after the image is inserted and you hit enter to type again I think it believes there is a change to the image on the enter hit and then ever consecutive key stroke after that.

Comment: I am convinced that the problem lies in the document.on(change) part of my code. I believe it is thinking when I type that their is a change to the file and is inserting the statement again realizing the text isnt a file and just leaves the div. But I dont know where to begin to fix this, or if that is the real problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, this happens only when you choose file to upload then type something and then choose a different file. You can either do `$('#post-image-container').remove();` before the prepend to remove previous div. Or you can check if `#post-image-container` already exist and simply update it instead of doing a new prepend.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `#post-image-container` already exists and simply update it. If it doesn't then prepend it.

```
 function readURL(input){
        if(input.files && input.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){


                if($('#post-image-container').length){

                    $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result); 

                }else{

                    $('#post-message').prepend("<div id='post-image-container'><img id='preview'/></div>");
                        $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result); 
                    }

                 }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I update the #post-image-container it takes away the image I have there for the post. Maybe I could try to do if it exists dont include again.

Comment: It will only update the image, keeping the text intact. Unless you want to be able to add multiple images... Please explain expected result more. Obviously the reason you end up with duplicate divs is because you're prepending a new one everytime you change upload input.

Comment: I figured it out notw it doesnt matter if its in there or not I just look through the text and replace every instance of the divs and classes before inserting into my database so it is only the text.